# composer update class phar not found

Tags: php, composer-php

my [php](/questions/tagged/php) version is 7.1.1

i'm trying this code to install react/zmq:

```
$ composer require react/zmq
```

but i saw this error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Phar' not found in /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar:23
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /cygdrive/c/ProgramData/ComposerSetup/bin/composer.phar on line 23
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Check, if the `Phar` extension is installed/enabled.
2. If installed, and not enabled - enable it in php.ini, or run command like this: `php -d extension=phar.so {path_to_composer_bin} require react/zmq`

Comment: how can i check [tag:phar] is installed?

Comment: `php -i | grep 'phar'`

Comment: it said nothing

Comment: Well, extension is not installed

Comment: i try php -d...
it said PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/phar.so' - No such file or directory in                                                                         Unknown on line 0

Comment: @newcomerstudent, INSTALL PHAR EXTENSION. Repeat again?

Comment: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/phar.so' - No such file or directory in                                                                         Unknown on line 0

Comment: is there another way to install?

Comment: how can i install that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ubuntu the Phar class does not seem to be included in the php cli distribution that comes preinstalled.

Locate the php executable file. It's likely to be on `/usr/bin/`

```
cd /usr/bin
```

Try and see if you have php files

```
ls -l | grep php
```

You might see php and php7.1 listed. If that's the case

```
sudo mv php php-old
sudo mv php7.1 php
```