# How to install Phar on Ubuntu?

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer-php, phar

I got into a situation where if I run `composer install` on my PHP project, I get this error:

`Fatal error: Class 'Phar' not found in /usr/local/bin/composer on line 23`

As I read [composer update class phar not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158996/composer-update-class-phar-not-found), I tried to check if Phar was installed by doing `php -i | grep 'phar'`, and Phar is not installed.

I am using PHP 5.6.

How can I install Phar on Ubuntu please?

[EDIT] When I try `apt-get install php-phar`, I get:

```
Package php-phar is a virtual package provided by:
  php7.2-common 7.2.7-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.1-common 7.1.19-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php5.6-common 5.6.36-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.0-common 7.0.30-1+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
You should explicitly select one to install.
```

Then, if I try `apt-get install php5.6-common`:

```
php5.6-common is already the newest version.
php5.6-common set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 295 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run `php -i|grep phar`

If it shows result something like :

```
/etc/php/{version}/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
Registered PHP Streams => https, ftps, compress.zlib, php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, compress.bzip2, phar, zip
Phar-based phar archives => enabled
Tar-based phar archives => enabled
ZIP-based phar archives => enabled
phar.cache_list => no value => no value
phar.readonly => On => On
phar.require_hash => On => On
```

Everything should be correctly installed.

If it shows no result or no phar ini files mentioned / disabled then you just need to include the correct ini on your main php.ini and set the path to `phar.so`files.

or if you locate the phar.so file just add it on your main php.ini with

`extension=phar.so`

or

`extension=path/to/your/phar.so`

### Update + extra to ensure ext dir location

It will be clearer if you grasp ini file location and ext dir used by your installation.

Try to do this:
`php -i | grep ini`

Then on the first/second line there will be your main ini file.

In my machine it shows this:
`Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/{version}/cli/php.ini`

then do this command to make sure ext folder used or any extension declared on main ini:
`cat /etc/php/{version}/cli/php.ini|grep ext`

You could also do:

`cat /etc/php/{version}/cli/php.ini|grep phar`

To check phar related parameter on main ini file.

If those step show nothing, I think it will be simpler if you just reinstall your php package on your machine.

Comment: `php -i|grep phar` shows nothing. If I run `locate phar.so` there are no results. I already tried to include `extension = phar.so` in php.ini but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Try to download phar.so manually from here: https://pecl.php.net/package/phar and then place it on /etc/php/extension/ and include it manual on your main ini. It seems your php installation doesn't setup the correct configuration file.

Comment: /etc/php does not exist. There is /etc/php5, but it does not contain an "extension" subfolder.

Comment: then you could download the extension and create extension folder yourself. Just make sure you locate the correct path for the .ini I will update my answer above to include the way to locate ini file and ext dir.

Comment: Sorry, since my last message I tried to uninstall all PHP and MySQL modules and reinstall them. But now I have an error during installation. To be honest I already had this error the first time and I force-ignored it, so it is very likely the source of the error. I feel that even if I solve the problem with Phar, I would have other problems since mods-available is empty...

Comment: The error during the installation is `dpkg: error processing package php5.6-common (--configure)`, `subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 10`. So this is a problem in the post-inst script used by dpkg. I located the line in the post-inst script that causes the issue, and it is `ucf /usr/share/php5.6-common/common/calendar.ini /etc/php/5.6/mods-available/calendar.ini`. When I run this command manually, it seems to work but nothing happens. The folder mods-available remain empty. Do you have an idea where this could come from?

Comment: I suspect your installation package is either broken or not compiled correctly. Have you tried to clean dpkg cache and reinstall them? Or ensure you use the correct distribution or ppa. Either way it became another problem altogether then. I think its just the matter of your php installation fo awry.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the extension first with:

```
apt install php-phar
```

normally it should register the extension automatically and it should work.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately it does not work (see my edit)

Comment: Then check which version is correct `apt search phar` then you should find all packages. Perhaps there is a package like `php5.6-phar`.

Comment: `php5.6-phar` is a proxy for `php5.6-common`, which is already installed :/

Comment: Then problem is i think you have added newer PHP sources. Normally you need for the new PHP 7.2 a PPA. So if you install them it's a problem if you use the old version then you have a mix. So perhaps you should install PHP 7.2 for your cli

Comment: My project only runs with PHP 5

Comment: Check witch common package you have installed `dpkg -l|grep php`

Comment: There is `php-common`, `php5-common` and `php5.6-common`

Answer (score 0):

If php5 doesn't recognize the phar.so lib, try to update to 7.x

The phar lib is auto included in newer packages and will be automatically configured as well. Hope that can help